# Behat : No such file or directory

Tags: behat

I just installed behat using [Behat's install instructions #1](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/quick_intro.html)
Every time I run bin/behat I am getting the following error:

```
bin/behat --init
: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix it? I am new to behat and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you run bin/behat --init?
2. Make sure it's **bin/behat** and not **vendor/bin/behat**.
3. Have you configured your .yml file?

Comment: bin/behat is a symlink that points to "../vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat". It is the "bin/behat --init" which is throwing this error. I dont have a .yml file, how should this look like?

Comment: From the sounds of it, it seems that the path is somehow incorrect (as a standard, it should be vendor/bin/behat).
The .yml file looks depending on your needs, but for a simple set-up, watch the video I linked below (behat.yml configuration starts at 2:15).
 I recommend watching it fully, though and redoing the whole setup. Behat's main documentation is shoddy at best.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9cYhnTojaHU

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
bin/behat --init
```

If you have see all the step in 'Behat's install instructions #1', you just have now a folder bin in your main directory (where you have your composer.phar and composer.json files) and inside this bin file, you have a behat file. 
Actually vendor/bin/behat it won't work because of this:

```
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin/"
}
```

And this code will create the bin folder. Hope it works for you.